# Laravel Storage Link on Sub-domain

Tags: php, laravel, image, web, file-upload

I have created a web application with **Laravel 7** in the local environment and it has an option where users can upload and change their profile image.
It works fine in the local environment.
Recently I uploaded this project to a live server under a subdomain. I put all the public files in the subdomain folder and other files in root.
Like this.
[File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0HiF.png) 
And now when I run

```
php artisan storage:link
```

It uploads images inside files/public/images
I need images into hello.example.com/images

**File upload code**:

```
if ($request->hasFile('profile_image')) {
    $image = $request->file('profile_image');
    $name = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $path = '/images/';
    $destinationPath = public_path('images');
    $image->move($destinationPath, $name);
    $user_image = '';
    if (isset($name)) {
        $user_image = $path . $name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To whom it concern I  have added
this in my index.php  
`$app->bind('path.public', function() { return _DIR_; });`

and remove fliestream.php links and it works for me

Comment: thanks for it, i tried this but somehow getting error `Undefined constant "_DIR_` any solution to this?